# Print name of variable as string without sending curly braces

Tags: javascript, variables, key, console.log

I've made a function for my own convenience that displays a log of the variable name and what it equals. The only way I've found to do this while retaining its original variable name is to send it with the curly braces, but is there a way to leave that out on the function call, and instead have it somewhere inside the function? I'm asking this because I simply want to type `clog(myObj)` and not `clog({myObj})`.

```
clog({myObj})

function clog(obj)
{
    const varToString = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    console.log(varToString + " = " + obj[varToString])
}
```

Comment: No. Expressions in function calls are fully evaluated *before* the function call happens. Thus, all that's left is the *value* of the variable, and not the name or anything else about the context of the call.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll have to hold down shift and type two more characters. Gawwwwd.